# GCS - Read a text file from Google Cloud Storage directly into python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I feel kind of stupid right now. I have been reading numerous documentations and stackoverflow questions but I can't get it right.

I have a file on Google Cloud Storage. It is in a bucket 'test_bucket'. Inside this bucket there is a folder, 'temp_files_folder', which contains two files, one .txt file named 'test.txt' and one .csv file named 'test.csv'. The two files are simply because I try using both but the result is the same either way.

The content in the files is

```
hej
san
```

and I am hoping to read it into python the same way I would do on a local with

```
textfile = open("/file_path/test.txt", 'r')
times = textfile.read().splitlines()
textfile.close()
print(times)
```

which gives

```
['hej', 'san']
```

I have tried using

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('test_bucket')

blob = bucket.get_blob('temp_files_folder/test.txt')

print(blob.download_as_string)
```

but it gives the output

```
<bound method Blob.download_as_string of <Blob: test_bucket, temp_files_folder/test.txt>>
```

How can I get the actual string(s) in the file?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`download_as_string` is a method, you need to call it.

```
print(blob.download_as_string())
```

More likely, you want to assign it to a variable so that you download it once and can then print it and do whatever else you want with it:

```
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
print(downloaded_blob)
do_something_else(downloaded_blob)
```

Comment: I'm getting `DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-storage' distribution was not found and is required by the application` error

Comment: how do i parse the tsv in gcp and turn it into json? (none of this is helping me).

Comment: As of today `download_as_string` is deprecated, in favor of `download_as_text` https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_text

Answer (score 20):

The method '`download_as_string()`' will read in the content as byte.

Find below an example to process a .csv file.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(YOUR_BUCKET_NAME)

blob = bucket.blob(YOUR_FILE_NAME)
blob = blob.download_as_string()
blob = blob.decode('utf-8')

blob = StringIO(blob)  #tranform bytes to string here

names = csv.reader(blob)  #then use csv library to read the content
for name in names:
    print(f"First Name: {name[0]}")
```

Comment: You've saved me!

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it for excel fiile?

Comment: @imjoymhnt it's the same process. you only need to use a library for processing excel files. Eg. openpyxl (ie pip install openpyxl)

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation (https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html), As of the time of writing (2021/08), the `download_as_string` method is a depreciated alias for the `download_as_byte` method which - as suggested by the name - returns a `byte` object.

You can instead use the `download_as_text` method to return a `str` object.

For instances, to download the file `MYFILE` from bucket `MYBUCKET` and store it as an utf-8 encoded string:

```
from google.cloud.storage import Client
client = Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(MYBUCKET)
blob = bucket.get_blob(MYFILE)
downloaded_file = blob.download_as_text(encoding="utf-8")
```

You can then also use this in order to read different file formats. For json, replace the last line to

```
import json
downloaded_json_file = json.loads(blob.download_as_text(encoding="utf-8"))
```

For yaml files, replace the last line to :

```
import yaml
downloaded_yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(blob.download_as_text(encoding="utf-8"))
```

Comment: This was the most straightforward solution as at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

**DON'T USE**: `blob.download_as_string()`

**USE**: `blob.download_as_text()`

`blob.download_as_text()` does indeed return a string.

`blob.download_as_string()` is deprecated and returns a bytes object instead of a string object.

Answer (score 2):

Works out when reading a docx / text file

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    # create storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('**PATH OF JSON FILE**')
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('**BUCKET NAME**')
    # get bucket data as blob
    blob = bucket.blob('**SPECIFYING THE DOXC FILENAME**')
    downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
    downloaded_blob = downloaded_blob.decode("utf-8") 
    print(downloaded_blob)
```