# I am trying to read a file in in Google Cloud Storage bucket with a python code but getting the error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jython, matillion

I am trying to read a file in stored in Google Cloud Storage bucket python:

```py
textfile = open("${gcs_bucket}mdm/OFF-B/test.txt", 'r') 
times = textfile.read().splitlines() 
textfile.close() 
print(getcwd()) 
print(times)
```

The file is present in that location but I am receiving the following error:

```
File "/var/cache/tomcat/temp/interpreter-9196592956267519250.tmp", line 3, in <module>
  textfile = open("gs://tp-bi-datalake-mft-landing-dev/mdm/OFF-B/test.txt", 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://tp-bi-datalake-mft-landing-dev/mdm/OFF-B/test.txt'
```

Comment: textfile = open("${gcs_bucket}mdm/OFF-B/test.txt", 'r')
times = textfile.read().splitlines()
textfile.close()
print(getcwd())
print(times)
Is my code

Comment: Do not put this in a comment. Put it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are trying to read it as a local file.

To read from Cloud Storage you need to import the library and use the client.

Check this similar [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279061/gcs-read-a-text-file-from-google-cloud-storage-directly-into-python).

In your case it would be something like:

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
client = storage.Client()

bucket_name = 'tp-bi-datalake-mft-landing-dev'

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blob = bucket.get_blob('mdm/OFF-B/test.txt')

downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()

print(downloaded_blob)
```

Also you will need to [install the library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/), you can do that simply by running:

`pip install google-cloud-storage` before you run your code.

Also here you can find some more [Google Cloud Storage Python Samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/storage/cloud-client).