# How can I read an avro file directly from GCS using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm running some python code on my local machine to read an avro file. The file originally existed in a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket however I downloaded the file locally so I could read it like so:

```py
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader

with open('/path/to/file.avro', 'rb') as f:
    reader = DataFileReader(f, DatumReader())
    records = [record for record in reader]
    reader.close()

print(records[0])
```

However what I'd like to do is read the file directly from GCS. I know I can write some code to download the file (e.g. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279267) however I'm wondering if there's a way to read the file directly from GCS without having to laboriously download it first.

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, afraid not!